# Unable to access sharedpreference from one class to another

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, classcastexception

Hi I am developing android openGL live wallpaper. I am unable to access shared preference from wallpaperService to renderer class.I am getting the error like:

```
06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):     at com.srashtaa.planets3dgalaxylivewallpaper.NeheLesson08Renderer.LoadPreferences(NeheLesson08Renderer.java:155)
06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):     at com.srashtaa.planets3dgalaxylivewallpaper.NeheLesson08Renderer.setContext(NeheLesson08Renderer.java:146)
06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):     at com.srashtaa.planets3dgalaxylivewallpaper.NeheLesson08WallpaperService$MyEngine.<init>(NeheLesson08WallpaperService.java:42)
06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):     at com.srashtaa.planets3dgalaxylivewallpaper.NeheLesson08WallpaperService.onCreateEngine(NeheLesson08WallpaperService.java:26)
```

This is my code:

```
         sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
         String rotspeed = null;
         String storedPreference = sharedPreferences.getString("rotspeed", "key");
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
         editor.putString("rotspeed", storedPreference); // value to store
         editor.commit();
         String check=sharedPreferences.getString("rotspeed", "");
         System.out.println("stored procedure values::"+check);
```

Here I am trying to get preference value,

```
               prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(value);
               storedPreference= prefs.getString("rotspeed","0");
```

Can anyone tell me why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who answered my question.All answers are appreciated.It was my mistake when I calling the preferences from another activity,the activity doesn't hold its context.Thatsy I unable to access preferences.

```
           public void setContext(Context value) {
mContext = value;

    prefs = value.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES,NeheLesson08SettingsActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);


}
```

I failed to place "value" infront of getSharedPreferences.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

This line states that you're trying to cast an Integer to String. Hence the crash. Make sure that if you've saved a value as String in your SharedPrefs, you're retrieving it as a String.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a String preference from where You had put some integer preference. You need to show us the code, so we can help You. I think You have done something like this:

```
 mEditor.putInt("KEY",1);
```

and You are trying to get this value with:

```
 mPrefs.getString("KEY");
```

Please show us Your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
      //Try This 

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("rotspeed", value);

        editor.commit();

   }

   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   String name = sharedPreferences.getString("rotspeed", "1000");
```

Answer (score 0):

The two parameters to `editor.putString()` are the key and the string you want to store, not a reference to the `SharedPreferences` object. For example

`editor.putString("rotspeed", "1000")`

See here for the documentation of `SharedPreferences.Editor`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

And here for a couple good introductions to using `SharedPreferences` in general:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html
[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)